# Change value of single textbox in a recordset

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset, ms-access-2003

First off I apologize for not knowing a lot about Microsoft Access forms.  I have had very little involvement with them and this is only to support a legacy product that will soon be replaced.

I have a Microsoft Access form that has a detail section such as the image below (shown in `Design View`).
[image]

I believe the first 6 textboxes are bound to a data set, the last one is bound to nothing (I added it for what I'm trying to do).  When I view the form in `Form View` I see many results (which come from the bound table).  The only textbox that does not have info in it is the last one to the right (Unbound).

My goal is to just simply change the value and back color of the following textbox in red.
[image]

I want to edit the contents (change "jk" to "Error") and I want to change the background of that one textbox to RED (vbRed).  The problem is when I try to change the backcolor it changes all the textboxes called "Errors" (that entire column).

```
ErrorHandler:
Forms![MyForm1]![Errors].BackColor = vbRed
```

If I want to get the value of the currently selected cell I can just do the following and it works fine...

```
MsgBox "Debug: " & Forms![MyForm1]![Code] 'The first column
MsgBox "Debug: " & Forms![MyForm1]![Name] 'The second column
MsgBox "Debug: " & Forms![MyForm1]![Number] 'The third column
MsgBox "Debug: " & Forms![MyForm1]![Errors] 'The Unbound (last column)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To edit and save individual records, the textbox must be bound to a field of the table.

So, add a field of Short Text to the table to hold your error message.

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up doing that and it works great.  Any idea how to change the color of just one row?  When I try to change the `BackColor` of the same object "Errors" textbox it changes all the textboxes in that column.

Comment: Yes, that how it works. You could try _Format Conditions_. If you can define some criteria for colour or no colour, it will do.